# Is a function $f$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ constant, if $f'(x)=0$ for all $x∈(a,b)$ but $f'(a)$ or $f'(b)$ are nonzero real numbers?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, constants

Suppose we have a function $f$ that is defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$. 
The following can be proven from the Mean Value Theorem:

If

- $f$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$
- $f'(x)=0$ for all $x∈(a,b)$

then $f$ is constant in $[a,b]$

The problem I have with the above theorem is the following:
If there exists a function $f$ such that all of the above conditions for the theorem hold true and additionally, $f'(a)$ or $f'(b)$ are non-zero real numbers, then, according to the theorem, $f$ would be constant for all $x∈[a,b]$.
Obviously, $f(a)=c$ for all $x∈[a,b]$ and $f'(a)≠0$ can't both be true at the same time.
Where is the problem here?

Comment: "Obviously"? Consider the function $f(x)=x^2+1$. Then $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$. I don't understand your point.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2 + 1$ is not constant. I meant that if the value of f(a) must be the same as the value of f(x), x∈(a,b), then how can $f'(a) be non-zero?

Comment: Ah, the letter $c$ appeared from the sky, so I had no reason to suspect you meant that $f(x)=c$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$. By continuity, yes, $f(a)$ must equal $c$ in that case. The function may fail to be differentiable at $x=a$. See my answer if the function *is* differentiable at $x=a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the Mean Value Theorem is that the function need only be *continuous* on $[a,b]$. It need not even be differentiable at $a$ or $b$ for the conclusion to hold.

However, *if* in fact $f$ is differentiable at $a$ (or $b$), then the derivative must be $0$. This is because of [a theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) which states that the derivative function always has the intermediate value property; thus, it cannot have jump discontinuities. If $f'(a)$ exists and $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f'(x)=\ell$, then $f'(a)=\ell$.

**EDIT**: Spurred on by @MartinR's comment, here's a much more direct proof.  Suppose the right-hand derivative $f'_+(a)$ exists. Since we've established that by continuity $f$ must be constant on $[a,b]$, then we have
$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a^+}\frac 0{x-a} = 0.$$

Comment: Was this the only problem with my reasoning? If $f'(a)$ could be non-zero, would that have been a problem for the theorem?

Comment: "If $f'(a)$ could be non-zero..." doesn't make sense, because such a function does not exist. Either $f'(a) = 0$ or $f'(a)$ does not exist.

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. Reread my last sentence. The point is that if $f'(a)=5$ and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$, then the intermediate value property is violated: Where on the closed interval $[a,\frac12(a+b)]$ does $f'(x)$ take on the value $2$?

Comment: You don't need the intermediate value property for derivatives. If $f'(x) = 0$ on $(a, b)$ then $f$ is constant on $(a, b)$, so the only possible value for $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

In the given situation, there are only two possibilities:

1. $f$ is differentiable at $a$ (resp. $b$) and its derivative must be equal to $0$.
2. $f$ is not differentiable at $a$ (resp. $b$)

So a function that is constant on $[a,b]$, has $f'(x)=0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and has non-zero derivative *at* $a$ and $b$ does not exist. The reason why we say it must have a zero-derivative on $(a,b)$ is just because the derivative in $a$ or $b$ need not exist.